# Andengine Banner Admob Black Screen

Tags: android, andengine, admob

I'm trying to add ads to a simple app, but when the app is running, the screen of the phone is black. I've tried almost all the solutions I've done in Google, but it did not. Is there anyone that can help me. Thanks

Codes

```
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

    public class comSpriteOlusturmaActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    private Camera camera;
    Texture textureResim1, textureResim2;
    TextureRegion textRegResim1, textRegResim2`enter code here`;
    Sprite spriteResim1, spriteResim2;


    public Engine onLoadEngine() 
    {
        camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
        engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true);
        Engine engine = new Engine(engineOptions);

        return engine;
    }


    public void onLoadResources() 
    {
        textureResim1=new Texture(128,128,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        textureResim2=new Texture(128,128,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

        textRegResim1 = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(textureResim1, this, "gfx/blueSmileIcon.png", 0, 0);
        textRegResim2 = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(textureResim2, this, "gfx/yellowSmileIcon.png", 0, 0);

        mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(textureResim1, textureResim2);
    }

    Scene scene;
    public Scene onLoadScene() 
    {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());    
        this.scene = new Scene();

        spriteResim1 = new Sprite(100, 100, textRegResim1);
        spriteResim2 = new Sprite(400, 100, textRegResim2);

        this.scene.attachChild(spriteResim1);
        this.scene.attachChild(spriteResim2);

        return this.scene;
    }


    public void onLoadComplete() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onSetContentView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSetContentView();

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8564721389464451/xxxxxxxx");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.refreshDrawableState();
        adView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
        adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("6C9CA739379F3C6E44B497FAF0876D4D")
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    }
}
```

layout: main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="serefakuz.com"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    .  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         >
        <activity android:name="www.serefakyuz.com.comSpriteOlusturmaActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Android version 4.2.2 and java version 1.7 in logcat info:

```
    01-06 23:01:37.005: I/PersonaManager(22804): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
01-06 23:01:37.276: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
01-06 23:01:37.276: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
01-06 23:01:37.276: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
01-06 23:01:37.276: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
01-06 23:01:37.276: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
01-06 23:01:37.276: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
01-06 23:01:37.276: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
01-06 23:01:37.276: E/dalvikvm(22804): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment
01-06 23:01:37.276: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 174 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
01-06 23:01:37.276: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0008
01-06 23:01:37.276: E/dalvikvm(22804): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment
01-06 23:01:37.286: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 174 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
01-06 23:01:37.286: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000c
01-06 23:01:37.316: I/dalvikvm(22804): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.h.a
01-06 23:01:37.316: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve static method 2946: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
01-06 23:01:37.316: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0080
01-06 23:01:37.336: I/dalvikvm(22804): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method hyx.a
01-06 23:01:37.336: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2339: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
01-06 23:01:37.336: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001c
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
01-06 23:01:37.426: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve static field 784 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_ABIS
01-06 23:01:37.426: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve static field 785 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
01-06 23:01:37.426: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve static field 784 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0012
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
01-06 23:01:37.426: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve static field 783 (SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0021
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
01-06 23:01:37.426: I/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0310 at 0x0d in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/internal/NativeLibUtils;.a
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
01-06 23:01:37.426: I/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0310 at 0x17 in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/internal/NativeLibUtils;.getSupportedAbisForCurrentRuntime
01-06 23:01:37.426: D/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
01-06 23:01:37.426: I/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x030f at 0x26 in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/internal/NativeLibUtils;.getSupportedAbisForCurrentRuntime
01-06 23:01:37.436: I/PersonaManager(22804): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
01-06 23:01:37.436: I/dalvikvm(22804): Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.ModuleContext.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext
01-06 23:01:37.436: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2232: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
01-06 23:01:37.436: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
01-06 23:01:37.436: I/dalvikvm(22804): Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.ModuleContext.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
01-06 23:01:37.436: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2233: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
01-06 23:01:37.436: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
01-06 23:01:37.436: D/DynamitePackage(22804): Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
01-06 23:01:37.436: D/DynamitePackage(22804): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
01-06 23:01:37.446: I/dalvikvm(22804): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.h.a
01-06 23:01:37.446: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve static method 2563: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
01-06 23:01:37.446: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0080
01-06 23:01:37.456: I/dalvikvm(22804): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method zz.a
01-06 23:01:37.456: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2120: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
01-06 23:01:37.456: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001c
01-06 23:01:37.486: V/WebViewChromium(22804): Binding Chromium to the main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {4201cdd0}
01-06 23:01:37.486: I/chromium(22804): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
01-06 23:01:37.486: I/BrowserProcessMain(22804): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
01-06 23:01:37.516: W/chromium(22804): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
01-06 23:01:37.516: E/dalvikvm(22804): Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity', referenced from method aat.b
01-06 23:01:37.516: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 777 (Lcom/google/android/chimera/Activity;) in Laat;
01-06 23:01:37.516: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x016f
01-06 23:01:37.516: I/Adreno-EGL(22804): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8960_KK_2.7_RB1__release_AU ()
01-06 23:01:37.516: I/Adreno-EGL(22804): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
01-06 23:01:37.516: I/Adreno-EGL(22804): Build Date: 03/25/14 Tue
01-06 23:01:37.516: I/Adreno-EGL(22804): Local Branch: 
01-06 23:01:37.516: I/Adreno-EGL(22804): Remote Branch: quic/kk_2.7_rb1.32
01-06 23:01:37.516: I/Adreno-EGL(22804): Local Patches: NONE
01-06 23:01:37.516: I/Adreno-EGL(22804): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
01-06 23:01:37.546: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1333 (common_full_open_on_phone) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$drawable;
01-06 23:01:37.546: W/DynamiteModule(22804): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found.
01-06 23:01:37.546: I/DynamiteModule(22804): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0
01-06 23:01:37.546: W/DynamiteModule(22804): Failed to load module via fast routeaje: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
01-06 23:01:37.556: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0060
01-06 23:01:37.556: D/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lig;.common_google_play_services_notification_ticker
01-06 23:01:37.556: W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(22804): Failed to load module version: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
01-06 23:01:37.556: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve static field 6317 (common_google_play_services_notification_ticker) in Lig;
01-06 23:01:37.556: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0092
01-06 23:01:37.566: D/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lig;.common_open_on_phone
01-06 23:01:37.566: I/dalvikvm(22804): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x18b5 at 0x62 in Llf;.a
01-06 23:01:37.646: I/Ads(22804): Starting ad request.
01-06 23:01:37.656: I/Ads(22804): Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
01-06 23:01:37.686: D/AndEngine(22804): UpdateThread interrupted. Don't worry - this Exception is most likely expected!
01-06 23:01:37.686: D/AndEngine(22804): java.lang.InterruptedException
01-06 23:01:37.686: D/AndEngine(22804):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
01-06 23:01:37.686: D/AndEngine(22804):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
01-06 23:01:37.686: D/AndEngine(22804):     at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine$State.waitUntilCanUpdate(Engine.java:712)
01-06 23:01:37.686: D/AndEngine(22804):     at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.yieldDraw(Engine.java:462)
01-06 23:01:37.686: D/AndEngine(22804):     at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:453)
01-06 23:01:37.686: D/AndEngine(22804):     at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:675)
01-06 23:01:37.696: I/PersonaManager(22804): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
01-06 23:01:37.716: W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(22804): Failed to load module version after staging: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
01-06 23:01:37.716: W/DynamiteModule(22804): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found.
01-06 23:01:37.716: I/DynamiteModule(22804): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0
01-06 23:01:37.716: E/AppStreamingFragment(22804): No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
01-06 23:01:37.726: D/DynamitePackage(22804): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
01-06 23:01:37.726: I/Ads(22804): Starting ad request.
01-06 23:01:37.736: I/Ads(22804): Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
01-06 23:01:37.786: D/OpenGLRenderer(22804): Enabling debug mode 0
01-06 23:01:37.906: I/dalvikvm(22804): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
01-06 23:01:37.906: I/dalvikvm(22804): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
01-06 23:01:37.906: I/dalvikvm(22804): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
01-06 23:01:37.906: I/dalvikvm(22804): Total arena pages for JIT: 14
01-06 23:01:41.981: I/dalvikvm(22804): Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.m.<init>
01-06 23:01:41.981: W/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2837: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMixedContentMode (I)V
01-06 23:01:41.981: D/dalvikvm(22804): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0058
01-06 23:01:42.051: I/dalvikvm(22804): Total arena pages for JIT: 15
01-06 23:01:42.872: I/Ads(22804): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-06 23:01:42.882: W/ActivityThread(22804): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
01-06 23:01:42.912: I/Ads(22804): Ad finished loading.
01-06 23:01:42.932: I/Ads(22804): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-06 23:01:42.932: I/Ads(22804): Ad finished loading.
01-06 23:01:43.052: I/chromium(22804): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
01-06 23:01:43.052: I/chromium(22804): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
01-06 23:01:43.693: I/chromium(22804): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
01-06 23:02:42.876: I/Ads(22804): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
01-06 23:02:42.876: I/Ads(22804): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-06 23:02:42.936: I/Ads(22804): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
01-06 23:02:42.936: I/Ads(22804): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need AdView in your main.xml 
like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: Thank you very much! it is working! I have another problem  Banner ad appears on screen but sprites are not appears on screen. Background screen is black.